# How can I change the published state of a node before it is saved with hook_entity_presave()?

Tags: 8, nodes, workflows

I tried adding this in entity_presave `$entity->setPublished(0);`  but the node still gets saved as published.  How can I make it be set to draft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested with hook_entity_presave() and setPublished(0) and setPublished(FALSE) both worked.  So the issue is somewhere else.

If you have workbench moderation installed, you may need to set it to one of your moderation states that set it to unpublished.

See admin/structure/workbench-moderation/states

```
$entity->set('moderation_state', 'draft');
```

or

```
$entity->set('moderation_state', 'unpublished');
```

or perhaps a custom moderation state.

Comment: As for *the issue is somewhere else*, it could also be the hook calls `setPublished()` on an entity that does not implement `EntityPublishedInterface`. The question assumes the entity is a node, but `hook_entity_presave()` is invoked for any entity, and the question does not show all the code for that hook implementation.

Comment: As for the *Content Moderation* module, it is true that it implements `hook_entity_presave()` with [`content_moderation_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21content_moderation.module/function/content_moderation_entity_presave/9), but hooks and form submission handlers implemented by Drupal core modules just calls `setPublished()` for an entity they want to publish/unpublish, without taking in consideration the *Content Moderation* module could be enabled and set the published value to a value that is different from the one they set.

Comment: $entity->set('moderation_state', "draft"); worked